# publish apache logs files

Tags: apache, debian, virtualhost

I would like to know if it's possible to allow some users to access to specific log files through an url like `httpd://www.mysite.com/ftpaccountname/logs`.

For the moment the log files are in the web directory of the ftpaccountname, but I would like to put them in `/var/log/ftpaccounts`.

And if I do that is it still possible to configure it in a way so that if the log file is full, the oldest content is replaced and to add some css styles to it ?

Comment: No direct method AFAIK as the /var/log ownership will not allow you to see via web. One method I am thinking is, Put a script to append the contents of the log file to a file inside the DocumentRoot of www.mysite.com say www.mysite.com/log.html. So that you can access via web. You needed to run that as cron to get this going

Comment: So, basicaly I've got two log files : one in /var/log an the other in the web directory and a script running in order to synchronise the content. If so, what should trigger the script in order to get the content of the log file in /var/log ?